# Why is it concatenating instead of arithmetic operation?

Tags: java, math, types, string-concatenation, integer-arithmetic

```
Scanner sal = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter first_salary: ");
int Salary1 = sal.nextInt();

System.out.print("Enter second_salary : ");
int Salary2 = sal.nextInt();

System.out.print("Combined Salary is " + Salary1 + Salary2);
```

I am trying to get user input twice, and then print the sum. Instead, the output is concatenating the numbers instead of actually adding them.

Comment: Because that is what you are doing, string concat. To add the numbers and then concat wrap the numbers with `()` like so `(Salary1 + Salary2)`.

Comment: So what arithmetic result are you expecting `"Combined Salary is " + Salary1` to give you?

Comment: Not sure why you got downvoted. The question seems clear, and is not at all intuitive to a beginner...

Comment: `"Combined Salary is " + Salary1 + Salary2` is equal to `("Combined Salary is " + Salary1) + Salary2` (left-to-right assoc). You want `"Combined Salary is " + (Salary1 + Salary2)`.

Comment: You might consider selecting an answer at this point...

Answer (score 7):

Because the `+` operator associates left to right. Your argument is equivalent to the explicit

```
(("Combined Salary is " + Salary1) + Salary2)
```

Since `("Combined Salary is " + Salary1)` results in a string, you will concatenate strings. To group differently, adjust the order of operations with parentheses:

```
System.out.print("Combined Salary is " + (Salary1 + Salary2));
```

Comment: Or avoid the problem altogether by using format strings, as in `"Combined Salary is %s".formatted(Salary1 + Salary2);` (or `String.format("Combined Salary is %s", Salary1 + Salary2)` if you're stuck on java <15).

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca. I haven't used Java since around 7, but didn't want to make it too obvious, so I stuck with the most basic answer :)

Answer (score 1):

As to *why* this happens, [@MadPhysicist's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70967718/133203) covers that.

As to how to avoid this you can either use parentheses as they said or you can use string formatting, like this:

```
System.out.println("Combined Salary is %d".formatted(Salary1 + Salary2));
```

`String` has had the [`formatted`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#formatted(java.lang.Object...)) method since Java 15. If you're stuck with an older version you can use the static [`format`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) method instead:

```
System.out.println(String.format("Combined Salary is %d", Salary1 + Salary2));
```

Comment: Or `System.out.printf()`